# Loading Bitmap into ImageView lets rotate the image shown

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-camerax

I have the following code which creates a Bitmap from a given image image file path:

```
private fun loadBitmap(filePath: String?): Bitmap {

        val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options)
}
```

It is called in the onCreateView() method of my fragment class:

```
bitmapOfImage = loadBitmap(args.getString(FILE_PATH))
```

The Bitmap `bitmapOfImage` is modified in a certain way with `RenderScript` and then it is loaded into an `ImageView`:

```
// do some modification on the bitmap
// ...

// copy modified pixels to 'bitmapIn'
allocationOut.copyTo(bitmapIn)

// load it into the imageview specified by its ID 'modifiedImage'
binding.modifiedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapIn)
```

So, I take the image with `CameraX` and the file path is passed along to `loadBitmap()` method of the image processing fragment mentioned above. 
But although I take the image in a portrait mode it is shown in a landscape version.

Here a little image how it looks like when I take the image:

[image]

But this is how it looks like after the bitmap is loaded into imageview:
[image]

As you can see the image seems to be rotated to the right. Why ? Is this happening by default ? How can I fix that ?
For the sake of completeness, here is my XML layout used to show the captured photo:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagecontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ImageModificationFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/modified_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shows_filtered_image" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: If you take a picture and immediately display it, is it in the wrong orientation? This will allow to figure out if the issue is related to the image capture or the processing that's done on the captured image afterwards.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem I commented out the modification part and set the bitmap returned from the loadBitmap() method directly into the ImageView. It is still in the wrong orientation. So, it does not have to do with the modification part.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired orientation, check orientation with [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface) and rotate the bitmap if necessary.

Example code below:

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Bitmap bitmap = 'your bitmap';
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes));
    int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```